# Scrape tables from wiki. Python with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape one table from all site but i stopped with that problem: i scrape only one cell and a don't know where is my problem. i need to scrape two first cells from all rows in table [that how i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwN8d.png). And how i can manual modify this code to other tables?

#### My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_TO = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammstein_discography'
response = requests.get(URL_TO)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable plainrowheaders" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    bells = row.findAll("th")
print(cells, bells)
```

My output:

```
[<td>
<ul><li>Released: 17 May 2019</li>
<li>Label: Universal</li>
<li>Format: CD, LP, DL</li></ul>
</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>5</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>3</td>, <td>9
</td>, <td>
<ul><li>FRA: 50,000 <sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-chartsinfrance_45-0"><a href="#cite_note-chartsinfrance-45">[45]</a></sup></li>
<li>GER: 260,000<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-chartsinfrance_45-1"><a href="#cite_note-chartsinfrance-45">[45]</a></sup></li>
<li>US: 25,000<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-46"><a href="#cite_note-46">[46]</a></sup></li>
<li>WW: 900,000<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-47"><a href="#cite_note-47">[47]</a></sup></li></ul>
</td>, <td>
<ul><li>BVMI: 5× Gold<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-musikindustrie_23-4"><a href="#cite_note-musikindustrie-23">[23]</a></sup></li>
<li>BEL: Gold<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-48"><a href="#cite_note-48">[48]</a></sup></li>
<li>SNEP: Gold<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-snep_44-1"><a href="#cite_note-snep-44">[44]</a></sup></li>
<li>IFPI AUT: 2× Platinum<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-IFPIAUT_30-4"><a href="#cite_note-IFPIAUT-30">[30]</a></sup></li></ul>
</td>] [<th scope="row"><a href="/wiki/Untitled_Rammstein_album" title="Untitled Rammstein album">Untitled</a>
</th>]
```

I need:

```
[Herzeleid]
[Released: 24 September 1995
Label: Motor, Slash
Format: CD, CS, LP, DL]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pandas` to do the table scraping

```
import pandas as pd

URL_TO = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammstein_discography'
df = pd.read_html(URL_TO)
df[1].loc[0, ['Title', 'Album details']].iloc[1]
```

The 0 above is for the fist record, `Herzeleid`

`Out[26]: 'Released: 24 September 1995 Label: Motor, Slash Format: CD, CS, LP, DL'`

You can save the table with

```
df[1].loc[:, ['Title', 'Album details']].to_csv('text_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: why i cant see 'Title' in out? and can it work on other wiki tables?

Comment: `df[1]` is the whole table, i just sliced the first cell, yes you can use pandas for all tables on the web

Comment: How to display "Title" separately? Can I have link to instructions for these commands that are in the code?

Comment: you can start [here](https://pbpython.com/pandas-html-table.html)